# Add metadata to specific subsets within a Seurat object

Tags: r, bioinformatics, seurat

I have a single-cell multi-omic Seurat object that contains RNA, cell-surface-protein(ADT) assays and metadata.
I subsetted the object based on ADT levels of interest. I want to add metadata to annotate these subsets specifically within the original object.

What I tried does not work:

```
data[subset]
```

gives the error:

```
Error in as.character.default(x) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Or data@assays$ADT[subset]

```
Error in GetAssayData(object = x)[i, j, ..., drop = FALSE] : 
  invalid or not-yet-implemented 'Matrix' subsetting
```

Or data@meta.data[subset] OR data@meta.data[[subset]]

```
Error in `[.default`(data@meta.data, subset) : 
  invalid subscript type 'S4'
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

UPDATE: It works using the approach:

```
# add annotation to each subset
  subset1@meta.data$newLabel<-"subset1"
  subset2@meta.data$newLabel<-"subset2"
  subset3@meta.data$newLabel<-"subset3"
  subset4@meta.data$newLabel<-"subset4"  

# function that merges the metadata of the subsets
    multiannot<-function(x)
    {
      CellsName<-NULL
      for(i in 1: length(x))
      {
        CellsNameInt <- subset(x[[i]]@meta.data, select = c("newLabel"))
        if(is.null(CellsName)==F)
          CellsName <-rbind(CellsName,CellsNameInt) else
            CellsName <- CellsNameInt
      }
      return(CellsName)
    }

# call the function using a vector that contains the subsets
  metadatanew<-multiannot(c(subset1,subset2,subset3,subset4))

# add the metadata to the original object
  data<-AddMetaData(data, metadatanew)
```

Comment: This is a very specific question requiring some knowledge about a specialist library. You might get a better response at the [Bioinformatics forum](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/) or even the [Seurat discussion page](https://github.com/satijalab/seurat/discussions).

Answer (score 1):

From what I uderstood you question is already answered here:
[Add Metadata to Seurat Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42279766/add-metadata-to-seurat-object?rq=1)

I am assuming you have successfully subset your object already based on what you wrote in your question.
One way to add metadata back to the original object is the following:

```
    CellsMetaTrim <- subset(data@meta.data, select = c("name_of_column"))
    #data is your seurat object with only ADT

    #"name_of_column" is the name of the annotation column you want to transfer from ADT data set to the object will all your cells.

    head(CellsMetaTrim)

    All_Data_Atlas <- AddMetaData(All_Data_Atlas, CellsMetaTrim)
    #All_Data_Atlas is the seurat object with all the cells.
```

Let me know if it works

Alternatively if you have a metadata column in your object with all the cells that distinguishes between ADT and non you can also create a new metadata column and modify it if it matches a certain value in said column:

```
     All_Data_Atlas$newLabel <- as.character(All_Data_Atlas$orig.ident)
     #orig.ident is the metadata column where you have labelled ADT from the other cells
     #$newLabel is the column for the new metadata
     All_Data_Atlas$newLabel  <- replace(All_Data_Atlas$newLabel, All_Data_Atlas$newLabel %in% "ADT", "New_Information")
```

In case you want to add metadata from multiple datasets you can use rbind on CellsMetaTrim:
First make sure all the datasets have matching column names for the datacolumn you want to add, you can do this by creating a new column if you have to:

```
data$newLabel <- data1$oldLabel1 
data$newLabel <- data2$oldLabel2 
#Then obtain multiple CellsMetaTrim and bind them together:
CellsMetaTrim1 <- subset(data@meta.data, select = c("newLabel")) 
CellsMetaTrim2 <- subset(data@meta.data, select = c("newLabel")) 
CellsMetaTrim<-rbind(CellsMetaTrim2,CellsMetaTrim1) 
#Now you can add it to your dataset
All_Data_Atlas <- AddMetaData(All_Data_Atlas, CellsMetaTrim)
```

Comment: Thank you Luca, the first option works for a single annotation. However, the problem now is that I have 10 subsets that I need to annotate, and I would like to have them all within the same column, as they should be mutually exclusive. If I use AddMetaData more than once, it overwrites the values completely as opposed to adding where there are NAs only. Any ideas how to overcome this?

Comment: I tried coalesce(CellsMetaTrim,CellsMetaTrim1) but they would not work due to different sizes of course.

Comment: I remember having a similar issue.
You can solve it with rbind() function:
You just need to have the columns from the 10 different objects labelled with the same name. You can do this by creating a new column if you have to:

data$newLabel <- data1$oldLabel1
data$newLabel <- data2$oldLabel2
CellsMetaTrim1 <- subset(data@meta.data, select = c("newLabel"))
CellsMetaTrim2 <- subset(data@meta.data, select = c("newLabel"))

CellsMetaTrim<-rbind(CellsMetaTrim2,CellsMetaTrim1)

Now you can add all the metadata together:
All_Data_Atlas <- AddMetaData(All_Data_Atlas, CellsMetaTrim)

Comment: I added my comment to the reply for clarity.
Let me know if it works :)

Comment: Thank you Luca, that worked! I also wrote a little function to simplify the code, if helpful for anyone looking for the same question:

Comment: `subset1@meta.data$newLabel<-"subset1"
# add metadata to all subsets
  subset4@meta.data$newLabel<-"subset4"  
    multiannot<-function(x)
    {
      CellsName<-NULL
      for(i in 1: length(x))
      {
        CellsNameInt <- subset(x[[i]]@meta.data, select = c("newLabel"))
        if(is.null(CellsName)==F)
          CellsName <-rbind(CellsName,CellsNameInt) else
            CellsName <- CellsNameInt
      }
      return(CellsName)
    }
  metadatanew<-multiannot(c(subset1,subset2,subset3,subset4))
  data<-AddMetaData(data, metadatanew)
  
  `